# After comitting, vscode sees git changes as not commited

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

- VSCode Version: 1.13.11
- OS Version: Windows 10 Latest

**Steps to Reproduce:**

1. Change a file
2. Commit changes

Result:

[image]

Comment: What does `git status` show you from the Bash?  If the bash reports correctly but your plugin does not, then maybe the plugin is the problem, not Git.

Comment: nothing to commit, working tree clean <- reports correctly

Comment: Have you saved inside VSCode?

Comment: Sure. I saved, commit (doesn't matter, inside or outside of VCS). Webstorm works fine, VSCode says that there are changes or additions after the commit.